Can't add a record to a database table using Entity Framework 6 when the model is complex having sub tables in it
I have a model class like this:
public class LvsBk 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string species { get; set; }
    virtual LvsSpecies LvsSpecies { get; set; }
    int GridNo { get; set; }
    virtual LvsGrid Grid { get; set; }
}

public class LvsSpecies
{
    [Key]
    string species { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}

public class LvsGrid
{
    [Key]
    int GridNo { get; set; }
    string species { get; set; }
    virtual LvsSpecies species { get; set; }
}

If I try this:
await _db.Lvsbk.AddAsync(new LvsBk 
                             {
                                 Site = request.LvsBkAddEdit.site,
                                 Species = request.LvsBkAddEdit.species,
                                 Grid = request.LvsBkAddEdit.GridNo
                             });
await _db.SaveChangesAsync(canceallatioToken);

I get an error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Threading.ExecutionContext&' of property 'Context' on type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder1+AsyncStateMachineBox1[LvsModels.Dtos.ServiceResponse1[System.Collections.Generic.List1[LvsModels.CSVModels.LvsBkIMP]],LVSApi.Services.ImportService+d__3]' is invalid for serialization or deserialization because it is a pointer type, is a ref struct, or contains generic parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.

And if bring in the referenced tables like this
LvsSpecies = request.LvsBkAddEdit.LvsSpecies,
PriceGrid = request.LvsBkAddEdit.PriceGrid

I get this error:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The instance of entity type 'LvsSpecies' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Species: B}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.)

I have already tried
_db.Entry<LvsSpecies>(request.LvsBkAddEdit.LvsSpecies).State = EntityState.Detached;
_db.Entry<PriceGrid>(request.LvsBkAddEdit.PriceGrid).State = EntityState.Detached;

To be clear this code is in a MediatR handler and request.LvsBkAddEdit is an lvsbk coming in from the MediatR command; _db is the Entity Framework data context.

The error says nothing about Entity Framework. It's a serialization error abut ServiceResponse<System.Collections.Generic.List<LvsBkIMP>,....>. None of these types is shown in the question.  EF is an ORM and deals with entities, not tables. It has no problem with child entities. Nor is there any need for AddAsync, that's only meant for highly specialized identity generators like HiLo that need to talk to the database to get a sequence range or high bytes. SaveChanges persists all the changes found in the tracked objects and effectively commits the Unit-of-Work

Post the full exception text returned by Exception.ToString() and the code that actually throws. I suspect the code fails to await an asynchronous operation and tries to store the task instead of the task's result.
